# Phonegap / cordova keystore for phonegap build no extension

Tags: cordova, build, key, sign

I'm switching from the phonegap / cordova CLI to phonegap build to compile my apps.
i used to use the commands

1. phonegap build android
2. cd platforms/android
3. ant release

i had a ant.properties file containing this code:

```
key.store = /Users/xx/myAppKey
key.alias = myApp
```

As you can see, the myAppKey what should be a .keystore file doesn't have an extension and therefore phonegap build is refusing this file to be a signing key file. How can i solve this issue because i'd like to do all this by using phonegap build from now on, including the key signing

EDIT:
I found the solution.
I used the following commands to resolve the issue.

first i converted it to a p12 file:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myKey -destkeystore myKey.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

then from the p12 i made a correct keystore file again:

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore myKey.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore myKey.keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

Comment: GREAT!!!!!! This is what  I was looking for!