# Build.phonegap upload or convert a p12 certificate file

Tags: android, cordova, keystore, phonegap, p12

I have my phonegap project with DevExtreme tool.
It is with phonegap cli-7.1.0 and it works fine.

Now I'd like to upgrade to cli-9.0.0.

I build the project with https://build.phonegap.com
Usually, I build ipa file here and I use the apk as template to compile the apk to publish with DevExtreme tool.

I created a template apk but when I try to use it in DevExtreme, I got error"error build android package Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index".

So, I'm trying to compile the apk directly with https://build.phonegap.com
To do this, I need to import the same certificate I'm already using to publish the app in the store (right?). My certificate is a p12 file.

I try to upload the p12 file, but I get the message "Error: extension .p12 did not match expected (keystore)". Ok, so I googled to convert the p12 in "keystore". I found this command line:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore android_certificate.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12  -destkeystore C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin\xxx.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass xxx
```

This created a jks file, but when I try to upload it to build.phonegap I get a similar message: "Error: extension .p12 did not match expected (jks)".

So, how can I convert my p12 certificate to something accepted by build.phonegap and use it to create my apk file and publish it?

My problem is the app is already published, so I have to use the same certificate and not a new one (right??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found a solution. Converting my p12 file with this command works:

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore android_certificate.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore myKey.keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

[Thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339359/phonegap-cordova-keystore-for-phonegap-build-no-extension)